# Looking for most efficient way to generate lots of objects in Java to add to db4o database

Tags: java, oop, db4o

I'm trying to add a whole bunch of objects to a db4o database. It seems like you have to create a new object for each one, because if I just update the values in the old and store it again it just overwrites the record in the database and I only wind up with one record. So here's what I have that works:

```
for (String o : d.students) {
    Student stu1 = new Student(o);
    db.store(stu1);
    stu = null;
}
```

My problem with this is obviously I'm not doing anything with the objects that just got stored, just reassigning the pointer. I know Java's garbage collection should just take care of everything, but I also know Java's know for being leaky, so if there's a safer way to go about this I'd much rather do that.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The JVM's GC will indeed take care of the memory and there won't be any leaks.

Answer (score 2):

I think your assertion that *"Java's known for being leaky"* is misguided at best.

Simply assigning a variable in the scope of the loop is sufficient to trigger its collection outside the loop, assuming that the `db` component doesn't hold that reference. Setting the variable to `null` in the above is an unnecessary optimisation.

Comment: Okay cool, I was thinking that about the null. 

I don't know much about the actual mechanics of the garbage collection so if someone who knows what they're talking about says that what I've heard is misguided, I'll take their word... and go do some research! Thanks so much again!

Comment: Not in this sample but for more complicated cases setting the Xmn value for jvm also helps faster object collection.